# In ASP.Net MVC, do I have to manually create a partial class for validation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using Entity Framework to create the model classes for the website.

Here's an example of using validation properties on the class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace Mvc3Razor.Models {
    public partial class UserModel {

        [Required]
        [StringLength(6, MinimumLength = 3)]
        [Display(Name = "User Name")]
        [RegularExpression(@"(\S)+", ErrorMessage = "White space is not allowed")]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(8, MinimumLength = 3)]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(9, MinimumLength = 2)]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required()]
        public string City { get; set; }

    }
```

So, while this works, it's also a pain to setup, especially if you have many tables, and many fields.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, no or at least not that I've run across.  Whether you use your data (EF) models for the MVC model or not in either case you're going to have to decorate a bunch of classes (properties) with the attributes.

Personally I generally insert a business layer between my DAL (EF/NHibernate/etc.) and my UI layer (MVC) so my models in the UI are different from persistence.  But I still end up with just as many (if not more) model classes with attributes as I have for the DAL.

This may not help in your situation but you may want to take a look at the new validation features coming with the next version of [EF](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/10/class-level-model-validation-with-ef-code-first-and-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx) and see if the will help you any.

Comment: After reading your link, I guess I can create a public PARTIAL class with validation rules and have it combine with the generated EF classes?

Comment: You could, the next version of EF also allows using POCO classes for your models.  This link (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/08/announcing-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-release.aspx) on Scott Guthrie talks a bit about it.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using your models inside your views where you should have view models? In view models you don't have many tables and fields. You only have what's needed for the given view.

As far as validation is concerned, personally I use [FluentValidation.NET](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) to define validation rules separately from my view models.